# How update value in database table using condition?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need update 'status' field in table, `where id == question_id`. I tried this but it's not working:

```
Questions.update_all("status = status_id.to_i", 
               ["id = question_id"])
```

I have this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'question_id' in 'where clause': UPDATE `questions` SET status = status_id.to_i WHERE (id = question_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smth like this?

`Questions.where(id: question_id).update_all(status: status_id.to_i)`